# Word for light after it has passed through a window / glass

Tags: programming, terminology

The most evocative image I can think of for this is when the headlights of a car pass through your bedroom.

I need this word because I have a computer graphics application that requires me to name a class which has the projection of another object, and I don't want it to be either ProjectedVisualObject or ShadowVisualObject because the first one is just not the word I'm looking for, and the second one isn't really accurate because it still has all the color of the original object.

Answer (score 1):

In physics the light that passes through an object is called the transmitted light. Perhaps you could call it TransmittedVisualObject?

Answer (score 0):

"**permeating light**" or "**diffused light**" might fit also.

> **[diffused](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diffused)** *adj.* (of light rays) subjected to scattering by reflection from a rough surface or transmission through a translucent material; "diffused light"
>
> **[permeate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/permeate)** *v.* to pass into or through every part of: *sunshine permeating the room.*

Comment: Thanks for including the definitions, because these are not direct synonyms; diffused has a specific use, whereas permeating is more general. It would be dangerous to use diffused in this case, since light does not usually diffuse when going through glass, but rather refracts (if the glass is lensed).

Comment: Well, These are more literary ways to say it depending on how you use it in a sentence. Because also his headlight-bedroom example is a more literary usage than technical. "refracted" or "transmitted" are too technical but he can choose them for his context.

Answer (score 0):

If the angle of the light has changed, it would be called [refracted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/refraction).  Perhaps that is what you are looking for?